# Stop an infinite loop when correct reaction is met discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot command that gives a question and two emojis on the question's message for user to react. If you select the wrong emoji, the bot will tell you "Wrong", react again on the message, and wait for the user to react. I want to put this into an infinite loop that only stops when the user chooses the correct emoji. This is what I have worked so far:

```
            message.channel.send(`Question?`).then(sentMessage => {
                sentMessage.react('✅');
                sentMessage.react('❌');

                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                    return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id != `${bid}`; // bid = bot's id
                };

                sentMessage.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
                    var reaction = collected.first();
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                        var check = true;
                        while (check) {
                            console.log('?');
                            message.channel.send('Wrong').then(sentMessage => {
                                sentMessage.react('✅');
                                sentMessage.react('❌');

                                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                                    return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id != `${bid}`;
                                };

                                sentMessage.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
                                    var reaction = collected.first();

                                    if (reaction.emoji.name == '✅') check = false;
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

The idea is when the user finally reacts ✅ after first reacting some ❌, `check` will become `false` and the loop will stop. However, after first choosing ❌, the while loop is not running any code inside it other than looping `console.log('?')`. Can someone point out where I did wrong?

Comment: You won't want a loop that blocks your event-loop process doing this.

Comment: Does that mean I'm not supposed to put an infinite loop inside `then`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you send `Wrong` and put the reaction check logic inside `then` and wrap with `while`.
However, since `Channel.send` returns a Promise, it will end almost instantly, continue the loop while doing `Channel.send` and reaction logic simultaneously.
You can use an async function and call it recursively.
So the code would be this:

```js
message.channel.send(`Question?`).then(sentMessage => {
                sentMessage.react('✅');
                sentMessage.react('❌');

                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                    return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id != `${bid}`; // bid = bot's id
                };

                sentMessage.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
                    var reaction = collected.first();
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                        async function reactionLoop() {
                            console.log('?');
 
                            let sentMessage = await message.channel.send('Wrong');
                            await sentMessage.react('✅');
                            await sentMessage.react('❌');

                            const filter = (reaction, user) => ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id != `${bid}`;
                            let collected = await sentMessage.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
                            var reaction = collected.first();

                            if (reaction.emoji.name == '✅') await reactionLoop();                
                        }
                        reactionLoop();
                    }
                });
            });
```